# play framework handling json from jquery (with gson)

Tags: jquery, json, playframework, gson

I am trying to use jquery to send the following to a controller in play framework (1.2.3):

```
[{"name":"username","value":"abc"},{"name":"fullname","value":"abc def"},
{"name":"email","value":"abc@def.com"},{"name":"password","value":"111222"},
{"name":"password2","value":"111222"}]
```

In my play 1.2.3 controller (I am trying to use gson), I have tried using `JsonElement/Object/Array` as the parameter but I always get null for the `JsonObject/ELement/Array` inside the controller - not sure if this is the right approach.  Any suggestions would be welcome or a better way of handling this (I would prefer to send json from jquery - handle it in play for processing).

```
public static void testForm(JsonObject json)
```

Comment: I made a mistake in copying the json - the json is valid (and I've already tried jsonlint)

Comment: Not sure if this question is still active but have you tried calling `params.allSimple()` to get your parameters in a `Map<String,Object>` and see what you are actually receiving? It may be being passed into `body` which can be catch using `public static void testForm( String body )` and then from there pass into objects using gson

Answer (score 2):

If that is the exact json string you are using you are missing the end tag to the array `]` try adding that to the end.

Comment: thanks for responding - the missing element was simply a mistake in copying the json to stackoverflow.  The question is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

How do you send your json and how to you get it in your controller ? There is no automatic binding for json in play so you have to excplicit

```
MyObject myObject = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(request.params.get("myObject");
```

Comment: finally an actual response - I will look into this and revert with feedback.  Apparently, the first two responders are only good at catching typos.